# Customize CSS Variable for Vuetify/Nuxt Tabs Component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm building a site with Vuetify/Nuxt and I'm customizing the theme in my `nuxt.config.js` file like this:

```js
vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    treeShake: true,
    theme: {
      options: {
        customProperties: true
      },
      dark: true,
      themes: {
        dark: {
          background: '#291c07',
          primary: '#7d521a',
          accent: '#6b3d01',
          secondary: '#3b280b',
          grey: "#fff",
          neutralgray: "#fff",
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Then, in my `variables.scss` file, I have this:

```css
$heading-font-family: 'Permanent Marker';
$body-font-family: 'Neucha';
$font-size-root: 24px;
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';
$material-light: map-merge($material-light, (
  'background': var(--v-background-base, map-get($material-light, 'background')) !important,
));
$material-dark: map-merge($material-dark, (
  'background': var(--v-background-base, map-get($material-dark, 'background')) !important
));
```

Everything is working as expected except for the font color of a [Tabs component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tabs/#grow). It defaults to a grey value and I cannot figure out which of the color variables needs to be overwritten to change this default color. Does anyone know which variable controls the font/icons color in a Vuetify tabs component?

Answer (score 0):

Can you inspect the gray color with your browser devtools, in the `Elements` tab. You'll see what is the used variable.

I gave it a try, and it looks like you need to override this selector

```css
.theme--light.v-tabs>.v-tabs-bar
```

You maybe need to use it on `$material--light`? Not sure of your current configuration.

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's the `lighten5` variation of the `accent` color, which I've already redefined. Do you know how to customize the lighten/darken variants?

Comment: Maybe directly, as written here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/#material-colors Like `red darken-4`.